# Is there a way to handle exception globally in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, exception

In C#, we can call a method that takes a Function or an Action and execute that within a try catch. By doing that, we can handle all the exceptions in one place making it more manageable.

Since Java doesn't have delegates, it cannot be performed the same way. Is there an alternative?

---

We have 2 classes: A and B. B is a subclass of A. All the methods in B override the ones in A.

Will I have to handle all my exceptions in the methods in B or is there a way to handle it in A and just rethrow in B? My assumption is that I have to handle it all in B, but I want to confirm this.

Comment: What? Please show the relevant C# code. What do delegates have to do with exception handling?

Comment: Think of a method that takes a Function or Action as a parameter. In that method it executes the Function/Action in a try catch statement. So all rethrown exceptions in the Function/Action can be handled in this method.

Comment: And why can't you do that in Java with a `Function`, `Runnable` or `Callable`?

Comment: Can I? I wasn't aware that I could, which is why I asked.

Comment: Delegates are completely unrelated to this. So is the lambda syntax. This is just a question of design.

Answer (score 2):

C# delegates are not essential to what you describe—they are just another way to pass around references to arbitrary functions. The same is offered by plain-vanilla *objects* via the feature of polymorphism.

In classic Java you can pass around implementations of `Runnable` or `Callable`, and you can provide such implementations as anonymous classes. In Java 8 you can provide an implementation with the lambda syntax.

```
public static void runWithExceptionHandling(RunnableExc r) {
   try { r.run(); } 
   catch (xxxException e) { ... }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   runWithExceptionHandling(() -> Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/x/y"), UTF_8));
   runWithExceptionHandling(() -> { throw new xxxException(); });
}

interface RunnableExc { void run() throws Exception; }
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out you can organize all of your exception-handling code (in addition to exception-throwing code) the same way if you're so inclined.

Answer (score 2):

Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler eh) does approximately what you are looking for